# Matching value of data object in VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How can I retrieve the data from a data object in Vue?

I have data in this format:

```
datasets: [{
 text:"Cars",
 value: "[1,2,3]" 
},
{
 text:"Trains",
 value: "[1,4,10]
}
]
```

Now I from route props I get the following info:

```
this.selectedText= this.$route.name;
```

Where `this.$route.name` is `"Cars"` for example.
Now I want to take this use `this.selectedValue` to get corresponding Value from this array:
so if `this.selectedText="Cars"` then `this.selectedValue=[1,2,3]` or based on this I want to retrieve the value of given text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method and use this code to find out the matching one.

```
function setSelectedValue() {
    let matchingDatSet = this.datasets.find(ele => ele.text == this.selectedText);
    if(matchingDataSet !== undefined) {
        this.selectedValue = matchingDataSet.value;
    }
}
```